# Search result page > category defined or understood by Google to co relate with search query?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I searched in Google: `does nioxin work?`

One of the top results is:

> Does nioxin shampoo make hair grow? - Yahoo! Answers answers.yahoo.com
>
> › ... › Beauty & Style › Hair
>
> ---

Why is the category formed with `> Beauty & Style › Hair?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that for your site if you use [microformats](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/rich-snippets-testing-tool-improvements.html).

Comment: Thanks John. Any other information of such similar snippet (micro formats) or ways to make google understand the category of search query with their important keywords?

Comment: That pretty much falls into basic SEO. [This question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google) has a bunch of good answers to get you started.

Comment: John, I also observed that websites using micro formats does rely on keywords to be their in the url of their web pages. Any comments?

Comment: That's coincidence. You find those sites because they rank well and having keywords in your URL is a ranking factor. But microformats do not have anything to do with URLs. The two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I am sorry I meant DOES NOT rely on  keywords to be their in the url of their web pages.